# How can I make word suggest a title that include hyphens when saving?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have made a program that creates documents based on templates. I would like to have word suggest the title when saving based on a document number. The document number includes hyphens and word only suggests the first word before the first hyphen as title if you put it as the first line in the document or change the title in properties.

I tried to insert the title as the first paragraph, but it only suggests the first word before the hyphen. Same with changing the title in properties.

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing the issue.  In the meantime try assigning the document name using the text you wish to appear as a filename.

Comment: Experiments here suggest that it doesn't matter how exactly you try to create the file name at the beginning of the document body. Using constructs such as field codes or content controls doesn't seem to help - Word just discards certain characters such as hyphen/minus anyway. Which means the only way to "suggest" a name that includes those characters is using code, e.g. VBA. As @freeflow said.